# What is this 2-pin motherboard component and is it broken?

Tags: diodes, short-circuit, error, schottky

I own a ASUS FX505DT Notebook and the fans stopped spinning so I wanted to check the voltage with a multimeter. I accidentally slipped of one of the terminals and released some "magic smoke" next to the M.2 Slot. I shorted 5v and GND. I am not 100% sure of the origin of the smoke but since both fans are note spinning anymore I kept looking for unusual spots. This component catched my eyesight:

In the red square you can see the damage I assume is broken. My assumption is based on the dot next to the number two, where I guess the magic smoke left from. The Notebook has two fans, so I looked up the other side and found the component labeled R2. I browsed around and found it to be a Schottky Diode but I am unsure what exact model. I guess it might be a MBR0520-TP.

I measured it to be around 150 Ohm, no matter which way I probe it.
[image]

Comment: Could this be your motherboard schematic? https://www.scribd.com/document/651137264/Fx505dt-Fx505dd-2-0-Schematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem your assumption is correct, (SMT Schottky Barrier Diode MBR0520).
[Here is the datasheet](https://www.smc-diodes.com/propdf/MBR0520-MBR0540%20N0717%20REV.A.pdf).
On page 1 and at the top right of page 3 it shows the marking is R2.